# How to customize Mapbox Autocomplete search results to user location proximity?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to make an Android activity (in Java) using Mapbox. My search results using the Mapbox Places plugin currently show autocomplete suggestions internationally and I don't know how to limit these results to the user's proximity (ex: 50 miles).

My current implementation is essentially all the code Mapbox provides for this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/global-location-search/

I want to do what they are showing here, however this example is in JavaScript: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/local-search-geocoding-api/#optional-parameters

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how you want to implement search for your Java/Android project. Your options are best outlined at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/#search-options.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/global-location-search/ is an example which uses [the Mapbox Places Plugin for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/).

[The Plugin's `PlaceOptions` class features a builder method to pass a proximity `Point`.](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-places/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/places/autocomplete/model/PlaceOptions.java#L57-L65)

If you don't want to use the Plugin, [the `MapboxGeocoding` class (via the `.builder()` has a proximity method as well](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-geocoding/src/main/java/com/mapbox/api/geocoding/v5/MapboxGeocoding.java#L296-L308). [Here's a Mapbox demo app example that uses the `MapboxGeocoding` wrapper](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/geocoding/).